# Call Azure Monitor alert for Resolved status

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-monitoring

I set up sending email to Azure Monitor and I get a message - **Fired: Sev1 Azure Monitor Alert Script for ...**

After some time passes and the threshold values ​​do not exceed my filter, I get the message **Resolved: Sev1 Azure Monitor Alert Script for ...**, but I do not want to receive it. How can this be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an [Action Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-action-rules) to suppress email notification based on the alert's state.

Notice that you can set a single Action Rule at the Resource Group or even Subscription level to automatically suppress all of these notifications using a single rule